# Map one to one table relation to single entity using entity framework 4.1 Code First approach

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have a one to one relationship in the database between tables Account and AccountProperties as below.

```
CREATE TABLE Account(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  
    [AccountName] [varchar](255),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Account]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE AccountProperties(
    [AccountHistoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NULL   
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AccountProperties]  WITH NOCHECK
ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountProperties_Account]
FOREIGN KEY([AccountID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Account] ([ID])
```

I want to map these two tables to single entity using foreign key AccountID as below.

```
public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }        
}
```

Can someone give me the right mapping using fluent API?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896233.aspx